# Full String not displaying in title property when assigned from C# code ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties

I'm having a problem with trying to assign a string property of an object to the title property of a span in a aspx webform.

Basically, I have a string in the form of

"Hello this bright future!"

Assigned in the back end to a simple class as shown below:

```
public class DeviceDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FailureDetails { get; set; }

    public DeviceDetails(string name, string description)
    {
        Name = name;
        FailureDetails = description;
    }
}
```

The problem happens when I get to the front end and try to assign it.  I get the first word in the FailureDetails and nothing else...

```
<span title=<%: deviceDetails.FailureDetails %>><%: deviceDetails.Name %></span>
```

Is there something I'm missing on the assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add some quotes around the title like:

```
<span title='<%: deviceDetails.FailureDetails %>'><%: deviceDetails.Name %></span>
```

I have made here a JSFiddle where you can notice the differences between the two https://jsfiddle.net/5qb4LLv8/ . Without quotes it just displayes 'Hello'

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <span title='<%: deviceDetails.FailureDetails %>'><%: deviceDetails.Name %></span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind file

```
    public partial class Exception1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected DeviceDetails deviceDetails;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         deviceDetails = new DeviceDetails("Test", "My Test");

    }
}
public class DeviceDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FailureDetails { get; set; }

    public DeviceDetails(string name, string description)
    {
        Name = name;
        FailureDetails = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it had to be something really simple and it never occurred to me that you can just add single quotes on the front end.